# Configure Apache to send HSTS header only in virtual hosts using HTTPS

Tags: apache-2.4, hsts

We have an Apache 2.4 server that runs numerous virtual hosts, some of which use http and some of which use https. I would like to send the same HSTS (`Strict-Transport-Security`) header only in those virtual hosts that use https.

I realize I could add the `Header` command individually to each virtual hosts, but I would rather set it once in the Apache global config section. Is it possible to set it in the global config so that *only* the https virtual hosts send it?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use a if expression.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#if

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html

For example, untested

`# Check a HTTP header for a list of values
<If "%{HTTPS} == 'on' && %{HTTP_HOST} == 'ssl.example.com'">
    Header set HSTS ...
</If>`